# Upload a file in add/edit modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, jqgrid

I use MVC3 with razor and jqGrid.

My problem is I cannot get the path or document name, at the level of controller, when I click on the submit button.

In my `index.cshtml`, I have my jqGrid with the `edittype: 'file'`:

```
name: 'CHEMIN', 
index: 'CHEMIN',
width: 200, 
align: 'left',
enctype: "multipart/form-data",
method: "Post", 
editable: true, 
edittype: 'file',
editrules: { edithidden: true, required: true }
```

And the editurl :

```
 editurl: '/Barrage/PerformCRUDAction?idbar=@Model&iddoc=' + IdDoc
```

This is my edit modal

[Image Modal](http://s10.postimage.org/g1asa15vb/modal.png)

In the controller, this is my function that will add the document informations in the database with the path of the upload of the document (PATH)
this function must also upload the file (picture, doc, ...) a specify folder in the server.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult PerformCRUDAction(DOCUMENT doc, int idbar, int iddoc = -1)
    {
        //code that will add doc information in database
        //and upload file in the server

        return Json(result);
    }
```

The parameter `DOCUMENT doc` takes  all input values in the modal except that an input file PATH.

[image parameter doc](http://s16.postimage.org/c4wtes7ar/null.png)